# Malformed header from script. Bad header=HTTP/1.1 302 Found

Tags: http, cgi

I have a C++ program acting as a CGI script, and I am currently using Cgicc to do some of the parsing and formatting for me (though it will probably be replaced at some point). When constructing my response, I use `cgicc::HttpResponseHeader`, which will create me something like

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: www.bla.com
```

This looks pretty standard to me. However, the Webserver chokes on that, giving me a

```
<...> malformed header from script. Bad header=HTTP/1.1 302 Found: script.cgi
```

I found out how to fix this:

1. Remove the `HTTP/...` line
2. Add instead a line `Status: 302 Found`

And in fact, that is exactly what `cgicc::HttpRedirectHeader` does. I have now two questions:

1. Is this line `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` not standard?
2. If it isn't, why is `cgicc::HttpResponseHeader` doing that? If it is, why does my webserver choke on it?

Note I am not looking for ways to get around this, I know how to do that. I just want to understand whats going on.

Cheers
Ole

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `HTTP` line is standard HTTP, but not standard CGI.

Under CGI, the script uses a `Status` header to communicate the status back to the web server, and the web server constructs the `HTTP` response line from that status code.

Why `cgicc` is constructing the `HTTP` line I don't know - is it possible that you're not supposed to use that particular class in that context?  Perhaps that class is only for use with `nph` scripts?  [The documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/doc/lib_overview.html) does kind of imply that - after describing the set of standard response classes, it says:

*cgicc::HTTPResponseHeader is a more powerful, generic HTTP header class used to construct a full HTTP response.*

The implication is that it's unusual to use that in a normal CGI script.

Comment: Okay, that explains it. Is there than any way for me, using CGI, to specify which HTTP version I want to use (1.0/1.1)? I don't really need that right now, but out of curiousity would like to understand CGI better.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know whether standard CGI lets you control that.  You can take over the whole process using an `nph` script, in which case you can do anything you like.